# Write Build Properties to Java Artifact

Tags: java, maven, build

At the moment, every artifact (JAR, WAR, EAR) created in our company has a `version.properties` in the main directory, which contains information as the svn url, the build initiating user, the maven coordinates etc.

I wonder whether there is a Java/Maven standard for putting this kind of information into a Java artifact.

Comment: How are you currently creating that file? Do you maintain it in SCM?

Comment: @ernest_k It is created during the build on the build server.

Comment: Maybe others know better, but that is exactly how we do it (creating such files with maven during the build) and I've seen it be done like that many other places... but that doesn't mean it's 'standard'.

Comment: Usually you can add those information into the `MANIFEST.MF` file?

Comment: Are there restrictions for additional properties in the manifest.mf?